# Can't write to a folder of a group I belong

Tags: linux, permissions

I'm trying to write a file to a folder of which I've set the owner to "dev" and group also as "dev". "dev" is the name of the group which each developers is a member of. See below:

```
martyn@localhost:/var/www$ ls -l
total 3
drwxrwxr-x  3 dev dev 4096 May 30 22:16 project1
drwxrwxr-x  2 dev dev 4096 May 30 20:24 project2
drwxrwxr-x  2 dev dev 4096 May 30 19:51 project3
```

I can confirm that in `/etc/group` that "martyn" is a member of "dev":

```
dev:x:1002:martyn
```

So I figured that I could write a file to /var/www/project1 like so:

```
cd /var/www/project1
vi test
```

.. but when I try to save in Vim it gives me an error - `E212: Can't open file for writing`. What am I doing wrong? How can I allow any member of "dev" to access files and folders of this group?

Comment: Try `cd /var/www/project1; ls -la | head; touch fred`

Answer (score 0):

```
dev:x:1002:martyn
```

It doesn't look like `martin` is part of group `dev`: the format for `/etc/passwd` would be:

```
user-name:x:user-number:group-number:comment section:/home-directory:default-shell
```

So try to revert `dev` and `martin`, and see if that works better.
See for instance "[Howto: Linux Add User To Group](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-add-user-to-group/)" and grep for `martyn` after you type;

```
useradd -G dev martyn
```

Comment: Is there an easier way to do this than editing `/etc/passwd`?

Comment: @user3265472 yes, you could use `useradd` command: see my edited answer and its link.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I had referred to that page previously. I get the following error for `sudo useradd -G dev martyn` - `useradd: user 'martyn' already exists`

Comment: @user3265472 then `usermod -a -G dev martyn`, and check with `groups martyin`

Comment: Hi, thanks. This time I don't get any errors but just seems to be the same as before. Btw my snippet above is `/etc/groups` not `/etc/passwd`. It still won't let me write to a folder of group "dev" when I do `vi /var/www/project1/test`. `groups martyn` gives me `martyn : martyn dev`